# Performance Filtering a very Large Array full of datarows

Tags: sql, arrays, performance, powershell, datarow

I have created the following two large arrays using the code below:

```
$VPX_ENTITY = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $vc_DB_Name -ServerInstance $vc_DB_Server -Username $vc_DB_User -Password $vc_DB_Pass -Query $VPX_ENTITY_QUERY
$VPX_VM = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $vc_DB_Name -ServerInstance $vc_DB_Server -Username $vc_DB_User -Password $vc_DB_Pass -Query $VPX_VM_QUERY
```

Because I am querying a SQL DB the arrays items are all datarows. I need to do filtering on the arrays however performance is not create. Here is an example of what I have now.

```
foreach ($VM in $VPX_VM){
        $VM_NAME = ($VPX_ENTITY | Where {$_.ID -eq $VM.ID} | Select -First 1).NAME}
```

This works and is fairly fast, however this is only one of the properties I will filter on and have 20k objects to loop through. To run the entire script it would like close to an hour and I need improve that drastically or go another route.

Do I need to convert the datarows to strings to improve the speed? Can I improve the code above and make it faster?

I tried using:

```
$VM_NAME = ($VPX_ENTITY.Get($VM.ID)).NAME
```

However the results that came back were always incorrect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like  you are trying to filter where you get a match in both data table arrays.  Why not build a SQL query to get you that information and just return the filtered information you are looking for?

Comment: Well honestly I am not that good with SQL at all, not really my expertise and this is just one property that I am matching on. I have about 30 more from multiple different tables to match on. I can post the entire script here if that will help, however its just more of the example I provided above. I have read that hashtables actually out perform arrays when containing large datasets. However since I have so many properties per item not sure how to save as a ht. Again any help with the above code or how to improve it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://www.spjeff.com/2015/04/21/datatable-in-powershell-for-crazy-fast-filters/

Use Datatables and DataView. The ".RowFilter" filters in DataView are faster than others. The only problem is that you can filter for one field.